# Why is application running on Heroku not secured by Heroku SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

http://sambaza.herokuapp.com/: my application which should be protected by Heroku subdomain SSL is insecure and lacking an SSL certificate, why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to set `config.force_ssl = true` in your `production.rb` or `staging.rb`, for whatever environment you're using. You'll notice that `https://sambaza.herokuapp.com/` does render your page with the default certificate, it's just not forcing the usage in your settings.

See the heroku page for more information: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

Comment: Thank you, i just realised that then came here to clarify it ,what an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable this

## Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.

config.force_ssl = true
In config production.rb file